# AngularJS element onresize event - Custom Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, resize

Does AngularJS have equivalent to this:

```
elementObject.addEventListener("resize", myFunction);
```

I thought about about watches, but I don't think it's the good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom directive:

```
app.directive("myResize", function($parse) {
    return {
        link: postLink
    };
    function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.on("resize", function (e) {
            var rs = $parse(attrs.myResize);
            rs(scope, {$event: e});
            scope.$apply();
        });
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
<div my-resize="$ctrl.myFunction($event)">
</div>
```

For more information,

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)
- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)
- [AngularJS $parse Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse)
- [AngularJS jqLite API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angularjs-s-jqlite)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:
HTML:

```
<div resize-me></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
myApp.directive('resizeMe', ['$window', function($window) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            angular.element(elem).bind('resize', function() {
                //do something on resize
            })
        }
    }
}])
```