# How to check for new changes in an element every few milliseconds

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to implement a function that checks for change in specific property of an element for example:

HTML

```
<textarea #box ></textarea>
```

Component.ts

```
@ViewChild('box') box :ElementRef;
Somefunction(){
// checks every 100ms if there is any change in width of box
if so console.log(box.width)            

}
```

So how do I go about implementing this ?

Comment: have you tried the element's onresize event?... I guess for Angular, you'd use a custom directive, a la https://stackoverflow.com/a/45040134/4843530?

Comment: (resize) is used for window resize I think . And I want to resize an element

Comment: look at the custom directive.  You should be able to set that on an element.  Right?  I've no experience in Angular, so just taking shots in the dark.  Sorry if it does not help.

Comment: Hi there. I see you have raised another question regarding this issue. The answer to this question is not that hard, but isn't it perhaps, rather inefficient to fire that method every x ms?